# Fedora 15 screensaver won't wake up after about 10 hours

Tags: gnome, screensaver

I can switch to another Terminal via <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd>, but the screen remains black and won't wake up. Sometimes, it wakes up after several retries.

Any ideas to resolve it?

Comment: how many graphic cards does your laptop have?

Comment: Does `pkill screensaver` stop it immediately? Does `pgrep screensaver` actually output anything?

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like your system is going to sleep and not recovering cleanly.

Check your power-saving settings.  It may be 'hard' sleeping after a few hours of no activity.  You can probably set it to not do that.